# Unresolved Gstreamer dependencies

Tags: 12.04, gstreamer

I am new to Ubuntu, and I am trying to install gstreamer on Ubuntu 12.04.3LTS upgraded from Super OS 11.10 (a repackaging of Ubuntu 11.10 with more apps and plugins ex: vlc and wine) but am getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad: Depends: libass4 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
                           Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is to be installed
                           Depends: libcdaudio1 (>= 0.99.12p2) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libcelt0-0 (>= 0.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2-1) but 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libdca0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libdirac-encoder0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libdvdnav4 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libdvdread4 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libfaad2 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgme0 (>= 0.5.5) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13) but 1.0.13-3 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 (= 0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2.2) but 0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.36) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.36) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libkate1 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libmimic0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libmms0 (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libmodplug1 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but 2:0.1~r459-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libofa0 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libopenal1 (>= 1:1.13) but 1:1.13-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
                           Depends: libopenspc0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but 1.2.46-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
                           Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.36.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: librtmp0 (>= 2.3) but 2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.9) but 1.0.11-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libslv2-9 (>= 0.6.4-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libsndfile1 (>= 1.0.20) but 1.0.25-4 is to be installed
                           Depends: libsoundtouch0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libspandsp2 (>= 0.0.6~pre18) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10 is to be installed
                           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                           Depends: libvo-aacenc0 (>= 0.1.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libvo-amrwbenc0 but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but 1.0.0-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libwildmidi1 (>= 0.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libzbar0 (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libzvbi0 (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed.
```

Please what can I do, I've tried `sudo apt-get clean` && `sudo apt-get update` and change the server option to main server, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because of upgrading to a newer version, but some software were already installed so caused packages with unmet dependencies.

You can give a try to following methods to fix the packages with unmet dependencies:

- First uninstall the packages completely which have unmet dependencies such as `wine` and `vlc` and `gstreamer` itself. Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands in series:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get clean
  sudo apt-get --purge remove vlc && sudo apt-get autoremove vlc
  sudo apt-get --purge remove *gstreamer* && sudo apt-get autoremove *gstreamer*
  sudo apt-get --purge remove wine && sudo apt-get autoremove wine
  ```

  It should remove all the packages with unmet dependencies.

  - Once all the packages will be removed execute following commands to update/upgrade and install your packages:

    ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get -f install vlc
    ```

    you can replace vlc by wine also if vlc installed successfully or what every `gstreamer` packages you want to install.

Hope it will work for you without any problem.

---

**Here is the best solution for you**

I always use **Synaptic Package Manager** to fix such issues. Using it you can **forcefully** install other version of packages.

- Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages(*if you have, other wise it will show nothing*) try to fix all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.
- Search for packages you want to **downgrade/upgrade**, highlight it by simply clicking on it **do not mark(tick)**, chose **Package** from the menu -> **Force Version** and chose some other versions from the list. Then click **Apply** to downgrade/upgrade it. (*You may also get that the selected package depends some other package, then search for that package and repeat this step till you fix all*)
- now try to install your actually packages, it would install without any problem.
- You can get more help about [How to use Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Still not working,here's the error am recieving: The following packages have unmet dependencies: vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not installable Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.